# Why does the driver crash when creating/destroying many VertexBuffers

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0

When I create several VertexBuffers, destroy some of them, then recreate them, I get the following error:

The driver has encountered an unexpected error.

No line number or other debug information is provided. What could be causing this? I need to constantly re-create VertexBuffers, because the number of vertices changes, which is why I can't use a DynamicVertexBuffer and use SetData continuously.

Comment: @neil: on windows phone?

Comment: Yes. It crashes only on Windows Phone (HTC HD7 physical device), not not the emulator.

Comment: Why not just create a vertex buffer larger than you need and reuse it? (Or several that you can cycle?) All of the functions for interacting with vertex buffers (`SetData`, `Draw`) can specify the number of vertices or primitives actually in use.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the amount of memory use to an absolute minimum, as it's a very sophisticated game (which I'm creating for Linux, Windows, and Windows Phone 7). See video here (Windows) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JyLTuBk7dzc&feature=channel_video_title

Comment: @idwmaster: I just answered to neil, he suggested to update the graphics driver ;) but then he deleted his post

Comment: You can't exactly "update the graphics driver" on a phone (in most cases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Apparently; I can only Dispose() of five VertexBuffers at a time, so on each call to Draw, I only dispose a maximum of five VertexBuffers, and it works perfectly. This works, but it would still be nice to know WHY it works, and what caused it to crash to begin with.